# RuntimeBinder exception when using System.Text.Json.Serialize with dynamic type

Tags: c#, json, dynamic, system.text.json

```
public string PrettifyJson(string json)
{
    dynamic? parsedJson = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<dynamic>(json);
    var optionPrettyPrint = new JsonSerializerOptions { WriteIndented = true };
    string formattedJson = JsonSerializer.Serialize(parsedJson, optionPrettyPrint);
    
    return formattedJson;
}
```

Running the above, I get (only in Release, not in Debug!)

> Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException: The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties: 'System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize<System.Text.Json.JsonSerializerOptions>(System.IO.Stream, System.Text.Json.JsonSerializerOptions, System.Text.Json.JsonSerializerOptions)' and 'System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize<System.Text.Json.JsonSerializerOptions>(System.Text.Json.Utf8JsonWriter, System.Text.Json.JsonSerializerOptions, System.Text.Json.JsonSerializerOptions)'    at CallSite.Target(Closure, CallSite, Type, Object, JsonSerializerOptions)    at System.Dynamic.UpdateDelegates.UpdateAndExecute3[T0,T1,T2,TRet](CallSite site, T0 arg0, T1 arg1, T2 arg2)    at Test.JsonUtil.PrettifyJson(String json) in D:\gitlab-runner\builds\RVQYCTWy\0\jpsc\developer\api-test\JsonUtil.cs:line 22

It seems there is a problem to find the correct `Serialize()` overload, since the first parameter is `dynamic`, but I don't really want to have to put a generic type on `PrettifyJson`, and it works as expected in Debug mode.

Any hints?

Comment: Does using `object` instead of `dynamic` definitely not work? If this is always a JSON object, can you parse to `JsonDocument`? Can you provide an example of the JSON for which this fails? A [mcve] would be ideal.

Comment: @JonSkeet I'd love to provide an example, however I can not reproduce it myself currently. This error is logged by the application that ran in a client's environment :(

I just thought maybe this is a known behavior with a simple solution.

Comment: I suspect you'd get the same error in Debug if you provide JSON of "null".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can reproduce the problem: just pass in `"null"` as the value for `json`. At that point, `parsedJson` is a null reference, and there are multiple overloads that are applicable.

The fix is to just avoid using dynamic typing, which isn't actually buying you anything here as far as I can see - just use `object` instead:

```cs
public string PrettifyJson(string json)
{
    object? parsedJson = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<object>(json);
    var optionPrettyPrint = new JsonSerializerOptions { WriteIndented = true };
    string formattedJson = JsonSerializer.Serialize(parsedJson, optionPrettyPrint);
    
    return formattedJson;
}
```

Then when "null" is parsed in, you still end up calling `JsonSerializer.Serialize<object>(null, optionPrettyPrint)` which returns "null" back.